Existence of a mobius transformation
Assume that $w$ and $z$ are two distinct points on $\mathbb{H}$. Can we always find $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $ad-bc=1$ and $\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}=z$
I think, this is not true. I tried taking the points $w=i$ and $z=i+1$, then I am getting $\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}=i+1$ and upon simplification I get
$$\frac{(bc+ad)+i(ac-bd)}{c^2 + d^2}= 1+i$$
I was hoping to see $ad-bc$ but ended up getting $ac-bd$ and now I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Can you re-do the computation? You need to multiply $-ci+d$ both on denominator and numerator, so the imaginary part on top is $(ad-bc)i$...

@Yuval, Right. I made a blunder there

In general the answer is NO. In fact, with $ad-bc=1$ you can easily show that
$$\operatorname{Im}\left(\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}\right)=\frac{\operatorname{Im}(w)}{\left|cw+d\right|^2}.$$
Therefore, if $w\in\mathbb{H}$ is such that $\left|cw+d\right|\geq1$ for all $(c,d)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, then the imaginary part of $\frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ cannot be larger than $\operatorname{Im}(w)$.
